# Stop requesting iAds in ineligible countries with PhoneGap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, iad

We're using this plugin to serve iAd inside a PhoneGap app: https://github.com/shazron/iAdPlugin

iAd is only eligible in certain countries like the US and UK. How do we stop requests in ineligible countries?

Thanks!